# Do bitizens ever travel to floors other than their job and apartment?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

While playing the Find the Bitizen missions, I wondered do the bitizens ever travel to floors that are not their own?  I know they will be found in either their jobs and their apartments, but can they travel elsewhere?

This could make a difference for strategy with regard to dressing people in certain ways to make them easier to find...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speak to my experience but I have never found someone on a level that wasn't their job or their apartment.

I created a spreadsheet that records level & apartment to help with the Bitizen search. It was a bit of work keeping it up to date at the beginning but now that I have most Bitizens with higher skill dream jobs I don't need to update it as often.